# Assign a define constant to const char * in C

Tags: c, constants, assign

I'm not entirely sure which is the right way to assign a constant to a `const char *`. Are both ways okay?

```
#define MSG1 "My Message #1"
#define MSG2 "My Message #2"
#define MSG3 "My Message #3"

const char *opt1 = NULL;
const char opt2[20];

switch(n){
    case 1:
        opt1 = MSG1;
        // or should it be:
        strcpy(opt2, MSG1);
    break;
    case 2:
        opt1 = MSG2;
        // or should it be:
        strcpy(opt2, MSG2);
    break;
    case 3:
        opt1 = MSG3;
        // or should it be:
        strcpy(opt2, MSG3);
    break;

}
// ...
printf("%s", optX);
```

Comment: Much more clear now. Thanks!

Comment: Don't change the code that makes relevant answers below meaningless. Post and addendum *and* mark the answers that are applicable to your problem, choosing the best one as the selected solution.

Comment: @WhozCraig Sorry about that, originally it was a typo. Reverted.

Answer (score 1):

```
opt1 = MSG1;
```

will assign the pointer `opt1` to point to the string literal that `MSG1` points.

```
strcpy(opt2, MSG1);
```

will copy the contents of `MSG1` to the array `opt2`.

Since you are declaring `opt2` as `const`, it's illegal to modify the content of it, so the first way is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Either will work (aside from the fact that opt2 should be declared without a const qualifier, since you're writing to the array with strcpy).  The opt1 version is a bit more efficient, since it's just a pointer assignment, rather than a character-by-character copy.

Answer (score 0):

> The strcpy() function copies the string pointed to by src, including
>   the terminating null byte ('\0'), to **the buffer pointed to by dest**.

So `strcpy(opt2, MSG3);` will not be syntactically incorrect, but as opt2 is pointing to `NULL`, this will cause a segmentation fault (SIGSEGV).

**On another note:**

The compiler decides if `strcpy(opt2, MSG3);` will be lesser efficient than `opt1 = MSG3;` as most modern implementations are 'clever' enough not to .

@happydave is right, no `const`.