# C++ error: assignment of read-only variable

Tags: c++, constants, assignment-operator

I have some C++ code that returns this error:

```
error: assignment of read-only variable ‘parking’
```

The code:

```
char const * const parking= "false";

if (phidgets.value(PHIDGET3V_1) > 1000) {
    parking = "true";
} 
else{
    parking = "false";
}
```

What does this error mean and how do I fix it?

Comment: Any idea what `const` qualifier does ?

Comment: You should really read a beginner C++ book.

Comment: The code that assembles `message` also won't work.  (It won't even compile even if you take off `const`.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20207688/assign-a-define-constant-to-const-char-in-c, but you should really use `std::string` instead since it has the more intuitive interface.

Comment: Also if you are going to initialize a C string you should be doing `const char parking[]="false";` conversion from string literal to const char* is deprecated

Comment: @Mike: The conversion from string literal to **`char*`** is deprecated, initializing a **`const char*`** with is is fine.

Comment: I really wonder why this question has been closed, the mistake being totally beginner one doesn’t make simple, well formatted question to be invalid... You know, the error itself does not say what is going on, if you don’t know the code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You declared parking as constant pointer.

```
char const * const parking= "false";
```

So it will point only to string literal `"false"` and may not be changed.

Also this statement

```
char const * const message = "Value: "+ parking +" ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy";
```

is invalid. There is no addition operator for pointers.

Answer (score 5):

`parking` is set to be `const` (`char const * const parking = "false"`) so it cannot be modified.

When you do `parking = "true"` it raises compile time error.

How to reproduce the problem very simply to illustrate:

```
#include <iostream>
int main(){
  const int j = 5;
  j = 7;
}
```

`const` means constant, meaning you are not allowed to change it:

```
error: assignment of read-only variable ‘j’
```

Answer (score 2):

In your code you set up the parking variable with a `const`, this is telling the compiler that it will not be modified later. You then modify parking later by setting it to true or false.

Using `std::string` is far more idiomatic c++ though. So I would do this instead:

```
  #include<string>
  std::string parking = "false";

  if (phidgets.value(PHIDGET3V_1) > 1000) {
      parking = "true";
      //leds_on(LEDS_RED);
    } else {
      parking = "false";
      //leds_off(LEDS_RED);
    }
std::string message = "Value: "+ parking +" ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy";
```

`std::string` overloads `+` to do concatenation so it does what you think it does in the last line. Previously you were adding some pointers and that probably doesn't do what you think it does.